# When I create my 1st CollectionView using storyboard the CollectionViewCell has default insets from top?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

When I create my 1st CollectionView using storyboard the CollectionViewCell has default insets from top(in size inspector it shows zero but it bit down from top of CollectionView) and I cant move it to top, but when I create a second CollectionView and further CollectionView its cell has no insets from top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your storyboard, uncheck `Adjust Scroll View Inset` of the view controller containing the collection view.